# Change text color of page which is in form of UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image

I am making an app for book reading, the content of the book is in form of images and I want to change the text colour of the page (image). I have tried many of filters like CIFalseColor, CIColorInvert etc. background colour of the page is white and text colour is black. How can I change the only text colour to green etc. and how can I change the background colour of the image which is white now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using CIColorMatrix.

To transform black text on white to black text on green you can apply a CIColorMatrix to "turn off" the red and blue channels, so you'll be left with just green. Use [0 0 0 0] as the input vectors for R and B but keep inputGVector as [0 1 0 0]. White will become green (0,1,0) and black will still be black (0,0,0).

To transform black text on white to green text on white you can apply a CIColorMatrix to force the green channel to 1, keeping the others intact.  Use all the default input vectors except inputGVector which you set to [1 1 1 0]. White will still be white (1,1,1) and black will now be green (0,1,0).

Comment: Great! You can probably improve the colours by tweaking the values instead of having zeros or ones (including the bias which is added to the output colour) -- combinations of 0% and 100% give harsh looking colours.

Comment: thanks Got it, now I am trying to do this for other colours except rgb like orange, purple etc .. I'll be here if I need some help :D